# phonegap android redirect to url not working on samsung galaxy

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, samsung-mobile

I am having problems using phonegap build with a samsung galaxy S3 phone. Basically I am trying to set a cookie and redirect to a different page using javascript/jquery.

Unfortunately on the samsung phone it just reverts back to the main page.

```
$.cookie('uname', identifier, {expires:7});
window.location="secure.html";
```

This code works on the other makes of android phone - is there something 'special' with the samsungs ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use window.location.replace("secure.html") to change page.

Comment: Thanks - will do but my test phone has gone home for the night :)